# javascript:find screen resolution when having multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, screen, browser, multiple-monitors, screen-resolution

I am using this piece of code to determine the client screen resolution, and then logging it

```
<input type="hidden" id="DFF63C7E-FB32-49AE-8ADA-3AB5C4834FB0" name="DFF63C7E-FB32-49AE-8ADA-3AB5C4834FB0"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="565C07CF-0D37-41DE-B47D-A247E9BD231B" name="565C07CF-0D37-41DE-B47D-A247E9BD231B" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         document.getElementById("DFF63C7E-FB32-49AE-8ADA-3AB5C4834FB0").value = screen.width;  
         document.getElementById("565C07CF-0D37-41DE-B47D-A247E9BD231B").value = screen.height;
</script>
```

It worked OK when testing in my localhost, but what I found out from the production logs was that the screen resolution was always 480x640. Does anyone know why this happens ?

And I did some more digging and found that I could change the resolution of my primary monitor and regardless of whether I open my browser in primary/secondary monitor, it would always give me the resolution of the primary monitor.

Is there any way to get the screen resolution based on which monitor the browser gets opened ?

And obviously the next question is, if the resolution changes midway (say from control panel) or moving the browser from one to another, is there a way to detect/update it with JS ?

Comment: 480x640 is a peculiar resolution, like a phone in portrait mode. Is this a site for smartphones? It reports this value no matter the browser?

Comment: well its an "internal" website and users only use IE. And nope, its not for smartphones

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be that your production PC really has 640*480 screen resolution. Is there a reason to doubt it?
2. Javascript has no means getting out of its virtual machine to take even a glance on the real host, so you must implement your update mechanism by the same means you detect the screen resolution, whatever it is.

Comment: >>1. The client is hitting the production server, and I am trying to find the resolution of the client. I do not think the resolution of the production server would matter here (some one correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the dimensions of the window instead:

```
window.document.width //Get the width
window.document.height //Get the height
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your page.

```
window.moveTo(0,0); window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);"
```

it will resize your window to full width and height..

for example use

```
<body onload="window.moveTo(0,0); window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);" >
```